# Javascript change tag innerHTML based on input and length

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><script type="text/javascript">
    function echoinputdatahere(elem){
    var size = elem.value.length;
    if(var size value.length == 0){
        document.getElementById("ef1").innerHTML = "Default_Text";
    }
    if( size value.length > 0){
        document.getElementById("ef1").innerText = 
    document.getElementById("inputdatahere").value;
    }
</script>
<style></style></head><body><form action="#">
<fieldset>
<legend id="ef1">Default_Text</legend>
<input
    type="text"
    id="inputdatahere"
            onkeypress="echoinputdatahere(this)">
</fieldset></form></body></html>
```

....

What I'm trying to code is the following.  I want text in the `id="inputdatahere"` `onkeypress` to change the `innerText` of legend `id="ef1"` to the value inputed in `id="inputdatahere"` only if the length of `id="inputdatahere"` is greater than 0. Else if the length of `id="inputdatahere"` is 0, restore `innerText` of `id="ef1"` to `"Default_Text"`.

Please advise.

Comment: Where do you close the `</form>` ?

Comment: I'll correct it.  It was closed in other code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `oninput` event - someone could *paste* text into that field, right? :) You want to handle all cases!

Additionally simplify your code to this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <script>
    function echoinputdatahere(elem) {
    
      var val = elem.value;
      var size = val.length;
      
      document.getElementById("ef1").innerHTML = size>0 ? val : "Default_Text";
    }
  </script>

</head>
<body>

  <form action="#">
    <fieldset>
      <legend id="ef1">Default_Text</legend>
      <input type="text" id="inputdatahere" oninput="echoinputdatahere(this)">
    </fieldset>
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function echoinputdatahere(){
  var data = document.getElementById("inputdatahere").value;
  if(data.length > 1 )
    document.getElementById("ef1").innerHTML = data;
  else if (!data.length)
    document.getElementById("ef1").innerHTML = 'Default_Text';
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
<fieldset>
<legend id="ef1">Default_Text</legend>
<input type="text" id="inputdatahere" onkeypress="echoinputdatahere()">
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: This works too!  I noticed after the fact that I should have request >0 rather than >1.

Answer (score -1):

```js
function echoinputdatahere(elem){
    var size = elem.value.length;
    if(size == 0){
        document.getElementById("ef1").innerHTML = "Default_Text";
    }
    if(size > 0){
        document.getElementById("ef1").innerText = 
    document.getElementById("inputdatahere").value;
    }
```

Will the above code work? Is there a reason you have var size value.length == 0? Does your code have syntax errors?

Comment: Yes, the code I made likely has syntax errors.  I was trying to reverse engineer several other examples of code.